# Performance testing- Distributing user load across test scenarios in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How can I distribute user load across test scenarios in JMeter?  For instance, if I am testing an email system for 400 concurrent users, I would like to apportion the total peak user load as follows:

1. 100 concurrent users checking emails
2. 100 concurrent users replying to emails
3. 100 concurrent users composing new emails
4. 50 concurrent users sending emails with attachments
5. 25 concurrent users making changes to their settings
6. 25 concurrent users doing folder operations

I tried to create one thread group per scenario.  But, when I add a scenario to one of the thread groups, other thread groups vanish.  It looks like I can't have multiple thread groups and add one scenario per thread group.

Comment: thread groups vanish? your settings should work so can add more details on your current test plan

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches for implementing the scenario:

1. Using different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for different groups of users
2. Using single Thread Group and distribute the load using one of the following:

   - [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
   - [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information on each of the tecnhiques.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with `Throughput Controller` - this site has the clear explanation you have been looking for - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-user-load-distribution-using-throughput-controller/.

[image]